# Calling custom controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to call a method on Button click from my view. Below is the code in my view:

```
<button type="submit" id="1"><%link_to "Done", {:controller => :summary, :action => :done_order}, {:method => :put }%></button>
```

On click of this button, I have to delete a row from table and update the view with updated contents. Below is the done_order method in my controller

```
def done_order

        List.where(:tableno => @orders.first.tableno).delete_all
        redirect_to :action => :index

  end
```

When I click on button I need to delete all rows(for a particular table number) from 'lists' table and redirect to index, which will again fetch rows from lists table in @orders and pass it to view to populate.
In routes file I have defined as: `put "summary/done_order"`

Problem is its not performing anything on click. I have tried numerous suggested ways with button_to & link_to but everytime landing up with some error. If there's no error then nothing is being performed.
I believe there is some shortcoming in my understanding to implement this and I am missing something on trying alternate ways. Please advise. thanks.

Comment: Do you have a custom route added in your routes.rb for done_order action?

Comment: Yes. I have added put "summary/done_order" in routes file.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a route for this:

```
# routes
resources summaries do
  put :done_order, on: :member
end
```

This should allow to write something like this:

```
= link_to "Done", done_order_summaries_path(@summary), method: :put
```

I'm not sure what you've named your objects, but it doesn't seem you've followed convention. So that part is up to you, but that's the basic mechanism. Another note is that you've put a link inside a button tag. I'm not sure that's even valid. There's no need for you to do that. Just style your link to look like a button or use a button instead, or even a button with a form.